# Two useEffect vs two API calls inside one useEffect

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

When component mounts I need to get data from two API endponints. For now I have:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(loadSomeDataOne());
  }, [dispatch]);

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(loadSomeDataTwo());
  }, [dispatch]);
```

I was thinking to do it within one useEffect:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(loadSomeDataOne());
    dispatch(loadSomeDataTwo());
  }, [dispatch]);
```

Is there some difference between these two solutions? Which one's better?

Comment: No. I think first one is better if your project is going to bigger. For example: After some time you need to other condition to handle with both api's its very hard to manage in single `useEffect` . And also first one has better readability as well

Comment: Keep in mind you can tuck away `useEffect()` calls into a custom hook as well...

Comment: Voting to close as this appears it will attract opinionated answers. If all you need to do is dispatch an action (or two) when the component mounts, then the second option is the clear choice IMO, there's no need to split them out. Even if you needed to do more and more complex logic when the component mounts, I'd urge you to factor each "thing" into a callback and still call both from a single effect hook. @PatrickRoberts has a valid point about custom hooks though, but you really only need custom hooks if the logic will be used elsewhere.

Answer (score 3):

Nope. using multiple `useEffect` is mostly for subscribing the side effects to different variable updates. For example you might have:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(loadSomeDataOne(varA));
  }, [varA]);

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(loadSomeDataTwo(varB));
  }, [varB]);
```

This way, only the desired `useEffect` executes when either `varA` or `varB` is updated. If you want everything to run at the same time, then you just need 1 `useEffect`.

Answer (score 2):

In this article, you will understand about useEffect https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-hooks-fetch-data
For me: Because you want to call API only when component mounting you can write code like that:

```
 useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(loadSomeDataOne());
    dispatch(loadSomeDataTwo());
  }, []);
```

That means you only want two function load data call once